# How to save pictures on ORACLE 11G?

Tags: sql, oracle, image

I want to create a table with a picture as a field, how should i create the table and insert an image on it?

Comment: try using BLOB datatype

Comment: @Nithin could you please give me an example?

Comment: pls refer this http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LOBs/LOBS_30.shtml